# Dynamically add markers on a Leaflet Map using ASP.NET Core and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, leaflet

I am trying to dynamically add markers on a Leaflet Map using ASP.NET Core and SQL Server. I am using EF Core and I am able to connect to the SQL Server database.

I plan to use `BranchGeoLocationLat` and `BranchGeolocationLong` from my `Branch` model as the latitude and longitude to put the markers on the leaflet map.

What should my controller and view page look like for it to work?

Model:

```
namespace Website.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUserClass:DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationUserClass(DbContextOptions<ApplicationUserClass> options): base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<BranchModel> Branch { get; set; }
    }

    public class BranchModel
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Branch ID")]
        public Guid BranchID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter The Branch Name ..")]
        [Display(Name = "Branch Name")]
        public string BranchName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter The Branch Address ..")]
        [Display(Name = "Branch Address")]
        public string BranchAddress { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter The Branch Geolocation Latitude..")]
        [Display(Name = "Branch Geolocation Latitude")]
        public decimal BranchGeoLocationLat { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter The Branch Geolocation Longitude..")]
        [Display(Name = "Branch Geolocation Longitude")]
        public decimal BranchGeoLocationLong { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Branch Zone ID")]
        public Guid BranchZoneID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BranchZoneID")]
        public BranchZoneModel BranchZones { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I plan to use BranchGeoLocationLat and BranchGeolocationLong from my
> Branch model as the latitude and longitude to put the markers on the
> leaflet map.
>
> What should my controller and view page look like for it to work?

According to your description and code, I suppose you have already generated the BranchModel table using Entity Framework Core, and initialized the DB with test data. If not, please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to use EF Core with Dotnet Core MVC.

To display markers on a Leaflet Map using the BranchModel table value, first, in the controller method, create an instance of ApplicationUserClass and a GetBranch action method, then in the GetBranch method, query the Branch table to get the test data. You could refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-controller-and-views).

Code like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly ApplicationUserClass _context;
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ApplicationUserClass context)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
    }

    public JsonResult GetBranch()
    {
        //get the data from the Branch table
        //test data
        List<BranchModel> branches = new List<BranchModel>()
        {
            new BranchModel(){ BranchName="Branch one", BranchGeoLocationLat=51.5m, BranchGeoLocationLong = -0.09m},
            new BranchModel(){ BranchName="Branch two", BranchGeoLocationLat=51.495m, BranchGeoLocationLong = -0.083m},
            new BranchModel(){ BranchName="Branch three", BranchGeoLocationLat=51.49m, BranchGeoLocationLong = -0.1m},
        }; 
        return Json(branches);
    }
```

Then, in the View, you could use JQuery Ajax to call the GetBranch action method and get the value, then refer to the [Leaflet document](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html) to use this plugin and display the markers. More detail information, you could check the following code (refer [this sample](https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/)):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>    

<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #map {
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
    }
</style>
<div id='map'></div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.5, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    var LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
        options: {
            shadowUrl: 'leaf-shadow.png',
            iconSize: [38, 95],
            shadowSize: [50, 64],
            iconAnchor: [22, 94],
            shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
            popupAnchor: [-3, -76]
        }
    });

    var greenIcon = new LeafIcon({ iconUrl: 'https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png' }),
        redIcon = new LeafIcon({ iconUrl: 'https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-red.png' }),
        orangeIcon = new LeafIcon({ iconUrl: 'https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-orange.png' });

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetBranch', 
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                var lat = item.branchGeoLocationLat;
                var long = item.branchGeoLocationLong;
                L.marker([lat, long], { icon: greenIcon }).bindPopup("I am the " + item.branchName +" leaf.").addTo(map);
            });
        },
    });
    //L.marker([51.5, -0.09], { icon: greenIcon }).bindPopup("I am a green leaf.").addTo(map);
    //L.marker([51.495, -0.083], { icon: redIcon }).bindPopup("I am a red leaf.").addTo(map);
    //L.marker([51.49, -0.1], { icon: orangeIcon }).bindPopup("I am an orange leaf.").addTo(map);

</script>
```

The output as below:

[image]